# How to make bash scripts print out every command before it executes?

Tags: bash, scripting, debugging

For example, I have a simple bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/hello
ls
```

How can I make it display every command before executing it? Just the opposite effect of "@echo off" in windows batch scripting.

Comment: For those looking for what the `set` options are, you can find them [on this man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html).

Comment: You can simply extend shebang like this `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
bash -x script
```

or

```
set -x
```

in the script.

You can unset the option again with `set +x`. If you just want to do it for a few commands you can use a subshell: `(set -x; command1; command; ...;)

Comment: I have always used this to great effect.  The output looks a little dirtier than you might first expect.

Comment: By setting `PS4` you can tweak the prompt of `-x`. E.g.: `PS4='Line $LINENO @ $(date +%s.%N): ' bash -x script` (`date` will slow it down, though)

Answer (score 26):

These also work:

```
set -v
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash -v
```

But -v doesn't print the PS4 string before each script line and it doesn't trace the steps of a "for" statement (for example) individually. It does echo comments while -x doesn't.

Here's an example of the output using -v:

```
#!/bin/bash -v
# this is a comment
for i in {1..4}
do
    echo -n $i
done
1234echo

echo hello
hello
```

Here's the result of the same script with -x:

```
+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ echo -n 1
1+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ echo -n 2
2+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ echo -n 3
3+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ echo -n 4
4+ echo

+ echo hello
hello
```

Note that I included "echo -n" to add emphasis to the differences between -v and -x. Also, -v is the same as "-o verbose", but the latter seems not to work as part of a shebang.

Comment: Great explanation!

without doing any research, it looks to me like Verbose and eXplicit are what those two letters stand for.

Comment: I think -x is closer to eXecute.

Answer (score 10):

This should also work:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cd ~/hello
ls
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
set -o verbose #echo on
...
set +o verbose #echo off
```

Answer (score 5):

`set -o xtrace` and `set +o xtrace` are your friends (it is more verbose, than `-o verbose`, and the output goes to STDERR, as opposed to verbose, which seems to log to STDOUT).

See more tips [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
```

as the shebang line.

Including `set -x` in the script itself will enable the functionality while `set +x` will disable it.
Both of these methods will also work with the more portable sh shell.

If I remember correctly perl also has the -x option.

Answer (score 1):

goes like

```
language -x script
```

language = python, perl, bash
-x = operator
script = filename

hope it helps.

Comment: `-x` has nothing to with echoing in Python

Answer (score 0):

`#! /bin/bash -x` does what you want.